# How to Terminate Toast message prematurely?

Tags: android, toast

I have a toast message that runs on button-click. I have another button that starts another activity. 
The toast is Ok if the user is on that activity, but if user navigates to new activity before Toast is done displaying it just doesnt looks appropriate. How to end the toast as soon as activity is finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Close the view if it's showing, or don't show it if it isn't showing yet. You do not normally have to call this. Normally view will disappear on its own after the appropriate duration.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29)

I haven't try this...Hope it will work..

```
  toast.cancel();
```

**EDIT:**

```
Toast t = new Toast(mContext);
t=Toast.makeText(mContext,"text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
t.show();
```

And use `t.cancel();` wherever you want

Comment: Toast test; 
test.maketext(####); 
  ( and just before firing intent to start new activity) 
text.cancel();

Comment: It was running fine without these statements.

Comment: test is null i feel... create object with current context reference